# Using macros to calculate data from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it is possible to use a macro to execute a solver/what if analysis function while Excel focuses on a different sheet.
I set up a macro for both of these methods and they work fine for when I am currently on the sheet with the formulas and data but when I switch to a different sheet and execute the macro it tends to run into these errors "Error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"" and "runtime error 1004".
My code currently looks like this:

```
Sub Solver_alpha()
Worksheets("Input Output").Activate
Worksheets("Input Output").Range ("$B$7:$B$6")
' Solver_alpha Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Input Output").Range ("$B$7:$B$6")` What are you doing with this line?

Comment: I think it would select the data that I want to get from my "Input Output" sheet

Comment: I'm not too familiar with solver, but something has to be missing there - either a `With` or a `SolverLoad loadarea`.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `Worksheets("Input Output").Range ("$B$7:$B$6")` should always throw a `Run-time error 438`, so it needs to be with something.

```
Sub Solver_alpha()
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
Worksheets("Input Output").Activate

With Worksheets("Input Output").Range("$B$7:$B$6")

    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I don't really get what the With ... line does.
It just asks me to select data for my table but I don't think that is any useful to what I want to do.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @vatsk Basically `Worksheets("Input Output").Range ("$B$7:$B$6")` is invalid syntax, as far as I know... Something has to be changed with that line. I figured maybe trying to put it in a `With` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it work but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using VBA at all and just placed everything into one sheet to automate the process.
I recommend you do the same as it is near impossible to make this work